# ASP.NET Core disable Request Buffering (not response buffering)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, out-of-memory

I've found a good answer for control of response buffering. But I need to disable REQUEST buffering.

#### Short version of the problem:

I've found that there is a buffer in the background, filling up with request data. Breakpointing the request method doesn't pause this process, so its clearly being done by a background thread. I've followed some instructions (such as turning off FormValueProviderFactory) but they don't prevent this behaviour.

#### Long version of the problem:

I've implemented the code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1#upload-large-files-with-streaming-1).

The sample creates a filter attribute called DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute which the docs claim prevents the file being loaded into memory, but it doesn't have this effect. The filter is hit AFTER the request starts to be streamed.

But I've found that the entire request is still buffered into memory. It hits the request memory limit and starts to be stored in disk instead, but this is causing the server to run out of disk space. I have only a few hundred MB to work with as the service is hosted in docker. What I really need is for **the multipart request to be buffered only up to the point where I can read it**.

I'm using .net core 2.1 with AspNetCore 2.1.1

#### A note on Request.EnableBuffering

The name is incorrect - the request is always buffered, what this actually does is enable request rewind.

#### A note on IHttpBufferingFeature.DisableBuffering

This is is obselete. It has no implementation details. The obselete tag says

```
[Obsolete("See IHttpRequestBodyFeature or IHttpResponseBodyFeature DisableBuffering", error: true)]
```

but IHttpRequestBodyFeature [doesn't exist.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13165)

Disappointing because I got excited when this answer appeared!

#### More information

After some experiments, I have figured out a few things. I moved the request out of a controller and into a middleware.

```cs
app.Use ((context, next) =>
{

    var Request = context.Request;

    if (MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(Request.ContentType))
    {
        // a breakpoint here doesn't stop the upload
        var path = Request.Path;

// ...
```

But I find that there is a background thread filling the request buffer. I set a breakpoint inside the middleware, but I can still see the upload occurring in the background. The request buffer is still filling.

The answer may have something to do with possible configurations one can make to HttpRequestFeature.

#### Further information

in the callback from UseKestrel you can configure limits and there is a limit

called "MaxRequestBufferSize"

But this is 1MB by default. So clearly its not responsible for the full request being buffered to disk.

I also found [a github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3704) regarding buffering being configurable, mostly just a complaint that it is not. This does not fill me with confidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### At the time of writing, this is not possible.

`IHttpRequestBodyFeature` is not implemented or exposed, so there isn't a method available for us to call to disable request buffering. There is only a way to disable response buffering in **IHttpResponseBodyFeature** using the `DisableBuffering` method.

I searched on GitHub and found minimal results for `IHttpRequestBodyFeature`
https://github.com/search?q=IHttpRequestBodyFeature&type= furthermore supporting the idea the interface is not available or exposed to us yet. If you search `IHttpResponseBodyFeature` on the other hand you get lots of results from dotnet and aptnetcore.

I recommend an issue be submitted for  `IHttpRequestBodyFeature` not being available here:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues

I cannot find a way to disable request buffering in `IHttpResponseFeature`. There is no `method` provided to do so. However with `IHttpResponseBodyFeature` there is a `method` to disable response buffering; below is an example:

1. Add the following namespace

   `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;`
2. In the *IActionResults* where you want **Response Buffering** disabled use the
   `DisableBuffering()` method which:

> Opts out of write buffering for the response

```
var bufferingFeature2 = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>();
bufferingFeature2?.DisableBuffering();
```

Comment: @gburton I revised the answer can you give this a try ?

Comment: I was really excited when you first answered, as I thought you had found an easy solution. But DisableBuffering no longer exists. The interface IHttpBufferingFeature is obseleted (error=true, so you can't even compile if you use it) and directs you to an API which no longer exists. The quote you gave is WRT the response, not the request. You've put a lot of effort in and I really appreciate that but sadly the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @gburton why do you think it no longer exists? I reproduced the error obsolete error (when using IHttpBufferingFeature.DisableBuffering), but not with the code in the revised answer with IHttpResponseBodyFeature.DisableBuffering.

Comment: I just now noticed that the revised answer references the *response* buffer. So it will probably work, but its an answer to a different question! I do still appreciate the work you've done though. Wish I could accept the answer and give you that juicy bounty.

Comment: @gburton Okay I see the miss, this disabled the response buffering but you need REQUEST buffering disabled. The investigation continues, I am starting to wonder if the answer is this is currently a limitation or bug the other method was obsoleted and another method in a new a interface like IHttpRequestBodyFeature. I couldn't fine IHttpRequestBodyFeature used or implemented anywhere.

Comment: @gburton I've done my final attempt to revise the answer. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct. Its sad that we can't actually control this buffer, so I'm going to have to write an OWIN middleware instead. Historically, large file uploads wasn't very well integrated into asp.net and it seems to not be an important consideration in AspnetCore either.

Comment: Reading the comments from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13165 by Tratcher from Microsoft; "Honestly we hadn't seen any reported usages of that API, it's not hooked up to anything by default." Microsoft though it wasn't something commonly used. I'd almost argue 13165 that was closed should be reopenned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220136/discussion-between-gburton-and-vvvv4d).