# How to prevent HttpClient.PostAsync to fill up memory?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following function in my blazor webassembly app to upload large files to the REST server:

```
private async Task<FileModel?> UploadSingleFile(IBrowserFile file)
{
    using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    using Stream fileStream = file.OpenReadStream(file.Size);
    var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
    content.Add(fileContent, file.Name);
    var response = await HttpClient.PostAsync($"File/{_selectedDataset.ID}", content);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var addedFile = (await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<FileModel>>())?.FirstOrDefault();
        return addedFile;
    } // else do something

    return null;
}
```

The function above should be able to stream large files to the API server. It works fine with moderately small files, however testing with bigger files resulted in a out-of-memory exception on the client sied. Even before hitting the server enpoint, the `HttpClient.PostAsync()` method fills the clients memory, even though the stream doesn't seem to be copied somewhere by me.

I have already tried to use `SendAsync()` with an `HttpRequestMessage` with an `TransferEncodingChunked = true` header added, but got the same result. Somewhere behind the scenes the whole data stream is copied to memory. How can I avoid this?

**For completness, here is the full exception**

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory
> at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
> at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
> at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LimitMemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
> at System.IO.MemoryStream.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at System.IO.Stream.<CopyToAsync>g__Core|27_0(Stream source, Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.<CopyAsync>g__DisposeSourceAsync|1_0(Task copyTask, Stream source) at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<CopyToAsync>g__WaitAsync|56_0(ValueTask copyTask) at System.Net.Http.MultipartContent.SerializeToStreamAsyncCore(Stream stream, TransportContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer) at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<WaitAndReturnAsync>d__82`2[[System.Net.Http.HttpContent, System.Net.Http, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a],[System.Byte[], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
> at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.CallFetch(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Nullable`1 allowAutoRedirect) at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.<SendAsync>g__Impl|55_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Nullable`1 allowAutoRedirect)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AuthorizationMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
> at VisionServiceWasm.Pages.DatasetManager.UploadSingleFile(IBrowserFile file)
> at VisionServiceWasm.Pages.DatasetManager.OnUploadFiles()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

Comment: You can restrict the maximum allowed file upload size in Kestrel and in IIS (https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267), as well as explicit disable buffering so that data is streamed to your code, rather than eagerly buffered into memory (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63477710/1064169).

Comment: Why are you using `MultipartFormDataContent` to post a single file? Just pass `StreamContent` to `PostAsync` method.

Comment: @SᴇM The reason is simply that the API can handle multiple files on the endpoint and expects this format. On the client however I'm usually creating separate Tasks for each file and try to upload them in (semi-)parallel. However the issue is already apparent with a single file.

Comment: @MartinCostello Hmm, this seem to be settings for the server right? In my case the server is never even hit.#

Comment: Where exactly do you get the exception? On the post?

Comment: @Magnus yes, I have also added the exception message for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you mentioned in this case the server is never event hit, so the problem should be solved in client-side.you can handle uploading huge files by chunking them in the browsers.
There are some javascript library for doing that. you can check the following project:

https://github.com/Buzut/huge-uploader

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have already considered chunked upload, but unfortunately I need the files as complete streams since my server uploads them to a S3 storage and I would have to temporarily store them somewhere, which I am not a fan of.

Comment: Also, I'm actually interested in the answer to the question of how to prevent `HttpClient` from buffering the data.

Comment: @RolandDeschain you can check this discussion, : https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/27680

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer now, since it seems that at the moment chunking the files is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:** The below seems to be only relevant for large responses, not large requests. Will leave here in case it's useful.*

---

This has been documented in [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/60287) already. It's also poorly documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#httpclient-and-httprequestmessage-with-fetch-api-request-options-2).

You need to make two changes:

- Use `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`.
- Use `SetBrowserResponseStreamingEnabled(true)`.

Both of these mean you need to do this as a full `HttpRequestMessage` and `SendAsync`, rather than using `PostAsync`.

You are also missing a couple of `using`.

```cs
private async Task<FileModel?> UploadSingleFile(IBrowserFile file)
{
    using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    using Stream fileStream = file.OpenReadStream(file.Size);
    using var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
    content.Add(fileContent, file.Name);

    using var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"File/{_selectedDataset.ID}");
    message.Content = content;
    message.SetBrowserResponseStreamingEnabled(true);

    using var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var addedFile = (await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<FileModel>>())?.FirstOrDefault();
        return addedFile;
    } // else do something

    return null;
}
```

Consider also using a `CancellationToken` to allow the client to efficiently cancel the request.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to fix the issue, since the response is not the issue (as far as I understand `SetBrowserResponseStreamingEnabled(true)` enables streaming on the response, however I need to stream the request).  @Aboulfazl Hadi linked another issue above, which suggest that there is a problem with streaming from WASM. The issue is already closed, but maybe not yet published to a release version.

Comment: Hmm think you are right. Seems to be a separate issue for response streams

Comment: Concerning docs: yes this is somewhat confusing, there is a page for blazor wasm upload, that only consists of fully buffered `IFormFile`, then there is a separate File Upload page for ASP.NET in general, with buffered and streamed files - however here 1) the linked sample project is .net3.x and 2) they still copy the streamed file to memory for file checks on the server, while not stating that in the docs. Would be really nice if they add all scenarios for Blazor WASM separately.