# Is DotNetStreamReference exhausting my memory?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, filestream

I have a situation where I am getting this error when I am trying to download a file from azure blob container:
[image]

Here is the bit of code that runs when I download the file:

```
try 
{
   var fileStream = await _blobServices.ReturnBlobStreamAsync(blobName,_downloadProgress.CancellationTokenSrc.Token);
   using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: fileStream);
   _downloadProgress.CancellationTokenSrc.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
   await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", fullFileName, streamRef);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    Logger.LogWarning("Download was cancelled : " + ex);
}
```

And here is the JS code:

```
async function downloadFileFromStream(fileName, contentStreamReference) {
    const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
    const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
    anchorElement.href = url;
    anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
    anchorElement.click();
    anchorElement.remove();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

For context, the file is about 140 MB and I am developing on a very crappy laptop that is always running out of storage. I am suspecting the file stream is exhausting my memory , as smaller files (less than 60 MB) seem to download without any problem. The app on prod seems to be working fine. Can anyone please shed some on how to verify my doubt? I am not cancelling the download but it is throwing `OperationCanceledException`as shown in the image.

Comment: I am actually not 100% sure this applies to blazor server, but I have had a similiar issue with blazor webassembly in the past [Corresponding SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75743440/how-to-prevent-httpclient-postasync-to-fill-up-memory). Basically even if you work with streams in c#, the data is still stored in memory, leading to the leak. If you want to only handle streams and store directly to file for example, you have to do everything in JS. Not sure however if this applies to your issue, since mine was WASM and file upload instead of download.

Comment: you are using browser storage there... (and then cloning that object when creating the link element) you can avoid that by just returning a File directly from the controller/endpoint.  The browser will then save it directly to disk.

Comment: @browsermator do you mean save the file first in the server and then download it?

Comment: you can return bytes, memorystream, filestream... format is something like return File(contentstream, mimetype, filename);  I may have misunderstood, though... is this all done on client-side?